# Magento Sub Total Discounted Price and Original Price

Tags: magento-1.7, price, shopping-cart, totals

am using this code to get Sub Total (Special Price)

> $price=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

How can i get the Original Price and Special Price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `Price` and `special price` via below code.

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $productSpecialPrice = $item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice();
}
```

in `$cart` you got all collection of cart item and if you want to get product id,name you can can get from using foreach loop

Comment: How can i Get the total Getprice without the loop ?

Comment: means grand total or subtotal?

Comment: actually i wanted to show the total Savings on cart total page
Based on Original Price and Special Price

Comment: if the item price is 200$ and Special Price is 150$ i wanted to show this in Cart Total Page like 
**Sub Total : 150$ You Saved : 50$**

Comment: you have to can display this thing using `$price-$specialprice` simple

Comment: yes, but now using the following code am only getting the Special Price $specialprice=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();

How can i get the original Price

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and used a slightly different approach to get MSRP and Total Savings into the cart totals for all items.

Edit the following file: 
/app/design/frontend/{your theme}/{your layout}/template/tax/checkout

Add this to the top of the page:

```
<?php 
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) 
{
    $productPrice += $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    $productSpecialPrice += $item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice(); 
} 
$discountAmount = $productPrice - $productSpecialPrice;
?>
```

Then below this you will find the 2 areas where magento dispalys sub total. First one is for with and without tax, second is just without. Edit the one you use by adding the following code:

```
<!-- MSRP -->
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo 'MSRP' ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($productPrice); ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- SAVINGS // MSRP - SUBTOTAL -->
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo 'SAVINGS' ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo "-" . $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($discountAmount) ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<!-- SUBTOTAL -->
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This will display MSRP (before special price) with Savings above subtotal.

Answer (score 0):

Add savings under grandtotal.
file: ....../tax/checkout/grandtotal.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $this Mage_Tax_Block_Checkout_Grandtotal
 * @see Mage_Tax_Block_Checkout_Grandtotal
 */
?>
<?php
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item)
{
    $productSpecialPrice;$productPrice;

    if($item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice() > 0)
    {
        $productSpecialPrice += $item->getProduct()->getSpecialPrice();
        $productPrice += $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
    }

}
$discountAmount = $productPrice - $productSpecialPrice;
?>

<?php if ($this->includeTax() && $this->getTotalExclTax()>=0):?>
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Excl. Tax')?></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotalExclTax()) ?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php echo $this->renderTotals('taxes', $this->getColspan()); ?>
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->__('Grand Total Incl. Tax')?></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()) ?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php else:?>
<tr>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <strong><?php echo $this->getTotal()->getTitle() ?></strong>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <strong><?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTotal()->getValue()) ?></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if ($discountAmount >0) : ?>
<!-- SAVINGS  -->
<tr class="checkout_save">
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right" colspan="<?php echo $this->getColspan(); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->__('Savings'); ?>
    </td>
    <td style="<?php echo $this->getStyle() ?>" class="a-right">
        <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($discountAmount); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif;?>
```